# How to access MySql installed on Azure Virtual Machine Windows Server outside Azure VM/Publically

Tags: mysql, azure, cloud

I am having Azure VM -Windows Sever 2012 R2.
I installed MYSQL in it. I wanna access the MYSQL outside the VM.
I am not sure how to configure and access the same?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sw development, this is a pure admin question. The DBA sister site of SO can offer you more help.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: Move the question to the DBA site.